# preparing a row with one jCombobox jTableCell filling from db table and add it to jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

I use netbeans to drag and drop jTable. I build this table step by step. 
each step I prepare a row and fill it with values and one comboBox from db then insert it. thats works well, but when I want to insert comboBox not work!

```
 ComboBox_itemUnits.addItem(rs.getString("FirstUnit"));
 ComboBox_itemUnits.addItem(rs.getString("SecondUnit"));
 ComboBox_itemUnits.addItem(rs.getString("ThirdUnit"));
 ComboBox_itemUnits.setSelectedIndex(1);

 model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("ItemCode"), rs.getString("ItemName"), ComboBox_itemUnits});
```

every this is right .. values come out in jTable ... but combobox not work not appear! 
when i check combobox values it is OK!

Comment: You don't add components to tables/table models

Comment: I voting to close the question as it can best be answered by reading an appropriate tutorial like [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)

Comment: I still stuck .. I try all ways .. but not work because all ways talk about fixed combobox .. but my combobox change every row insert according to database table record

Comment: You need to read the tutorials, they will explain why trying to add a component to the model like you are is a bad idea and will provide numerous examples of how you can fix it

Comment: Ok , I will do .. I approached it approximately .. Thank you gentle

Comment: please .. leave this post opened .. I will post the answer soon.